# Bootstrap, <body class="container">

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Why do you always have to put a `<div class="container">` in? Why can't `<body>` have the class of container?

That means every HTML page starts with

```
 <body>
  <div class= "container">
  </div>
 </body>
```

It's kind of extra work/code/indenting/stuff to keep track of.

Comment: Because that's how they designed bootstrap to work....

Comment: who said you can't? but don't do that. it's hardly extra work and can cause you all sorts of trouble.

Comment: Of course you *can*, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @David Why not?

Comment: @str browsers do not treat body like a normal div. Internet Exploder will play havoc with it. You should know better ;-)

Comment: @David So? Adding `padding`, `margin`, `width`, and `max-width` rules to `body` is perfectly valid.